# Capturing pasted file

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

Google Docs supports pasting image files into the document. That is, you have an image file on your desktop, you copy the file, then you Ctrl+V into Google Docs. How does it capture this paste?

This code works to capture text and images (not files) from pasting.

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.clipboardData.items.length)
    for (var item of e.clipboardData.items) {
        console.log(item)
    }

    console.log(e.clipboardData.files.length)
    for (var file of e.clipboardData.files) {
        console.log(file)
    }
});
```

Output:

Text https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbxhr.png

Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUGci.png

Image file copied from desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxijQ.png

Answer (score 1):

They probably listen to the [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) event, which is a [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent), and thus has a [clipboardData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData)  property, which is a [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object, from which you may access its [files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files) property.

```js
inp.onpaste = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const files = e.clipboardData.files;
  if (files && files.length && !files[0].type.indexOf('image')) {
    var img = document.body.appendChild(new Image());
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" placeholder="paste an image file here">
```

Comment: That snippet doesn't work for me in firefox. (Google Docs does). Any idea why?

Comment: @ryan no idea, works for me on FF63 on macOs, but should work in any up to date browser. What's your FF version?